# Authenticate user using folder name (domain)

Tags: login, password, login-screen, authentication, password-recovery

I lost my password and login for Ubuntu and now trying to reset it. I use local machine with Ubuntu 18.04.
I found the right way (some guide) using such command from the safe mode:

```
passwd username
```

But my login use domain in it:

```
MYDOMAIN\mikhail
```

also I can check it using `ls` in `home` directory:

```
home
 |- baseuser
 |- MYDOMAIN
   | - mikhail
   | - anotheruser
```

Thats mean I have directory MYDOMAIN in home directory and some users in it. One of them - mine: `mikhail`.
I tried this command:

```
passwd MYDOMAIN\mikhail
```

And got error:

> there is no such user.

I tried all the possible cases:

```
passwd mikhail
passwd MYDOMAIN\\mikhail
passwd MYDOMAIN/mikhail
passwd MYDOMAIN//mikhail
passwd MYDOMAIN.mikhail
passwd MYDOMAIN@mikhail
```

How to write it in the right way?

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you for responce! I didn't get it. to create it I logged in using base user, run scripts for creating new user and adding it to domain. but lost my password after that. Did you mean I must change password through the Windows? I know Win password for this user, but it is incorrect in ubuntu :(

Comment: @Rinzwind it is local machine but there is domain of our company. Does it mean I can reset password using this Active Domain on win server (for me this mean as for support team)?

Answer (score 0):

You system is set it with active domain (AD). That means you need to reset the password on a Windows NT Server.

You need the [smbpassword](https://linux.die.net/man/8/smbpasswd) command to change it BUT it depends on the security settings on the domain server (ie. Windows NT) if you are allowed to use this method.

```
smbpasswd -U {USER} -r {IP_ADDRESS_DOMAIN_SERVER}
```

---

```
   -r remote machine name
       This option allows a user to specify what machine they wish to
       change their password on. Without this parameter smbpasswd defaults
       to the local host. The remote machine name is the NetBIOS name of
       the SMB/CIFS server to contact to attempt the password change. This
       name is resolved into an IP address using the standard name
       resolution mechanism in all programs of the Samba suite. See the -R
       name resolve order parameter for details on changing this resolving
       mechanism.

       The username whose password is changed is that of the current UNIX
       logged on user. See the -U username parameter for details on
       changing the password for a different username.

   -U username
       This option may only be used in conjunction with the -r option.
       When changing a password on a remote machine it allows the user to
       specify the user name on that machine whose password will be
       changed. It is present to allow users who have different user names
       on different systems to change these passwords.
```

If you get a NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED you need to ask your Windows administrator.